Can a foreigner initiate Hindus?
I have read that mlecchas can become Vishnu devotees but can they initiate Aryans?

"initiate" into what?

Mantra Deeksha/Guru Deeksha

In your future posts, can you please only ask your question and not say "kindly answer"? This is a Q&A site, not a forum, so such niceties are frowned upon.

In the strict sense of initiation, it's ability of teacher that counts.

Qualification of "Guru" is realization of Bhagwan and ability to initiate.
Geeta 4-34 mentions, learn from tatvadarshi. This is "the" qualification.''

No more, no less.

There is no mention of foreign gurus in scriptures

Finding an example in scripture, will be suitable for a different question.

This is Hinduism forum, where I have no example. But in Buddhism, you may trace - Marpa Lotsava getting initiated in India, initiating Milarepa in Tibet. Finally Tibetan Budhism coming back as Dalai Lama and kargyu Karmapa Lama. Search wikipedia for these names and get more details.
